# $A^{p}=I_{n}$ but $A$ is not diagonalizable over any finite extension $L$ of $K$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory

The following is a problem from my undergraduate algebra course. (Just in case, Galois theory was not covered)

> Give an example of a prime $p$, a field $K$ of characteristic $p$, and an $n$ by $n$ matrix $A$ such that $A^{p}=I_{n}$ but $A$ is not diagonalizable over any finite extension $L$ of $K$.

Solution: The matrix $\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right)$ has order $p$ in $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_{p}$, and its minimal polynomial is $(X-1)^{2}$.

Okay, I understand the solution. But my question is, how in the world could I come up with such a solution? What is the intuition for it, assuming that I am working it out by myself?

Comment: The simplest nondiagonalizable matrix in the universe is $\pmatrix{1&1\cr0&1\cr}$ so it makes sense to try it first.

Comment: typically in an algebra course, when covering rings, you are introduced to (i) Frobenius homorphism and (ii) something about if the characteristic of the ring is $p$, and $a$ is nilpotent, then $(1+a)$ is unipotent (easy proof: use Frobenius Homomorphism)-- understanding those things for commutative rings should allow you to realize $(I+N)$ is unipotent when characteristic is prime and $N$ is a nilpotent matrix)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can chase it out from well known facts.

Since $A$ satisfies $X^p-1=(X-1)^p$ you know that the eigenvalues of $A$ are all equal to $1$ and lie in $K$. So without loss of generality $A$ is upper unitriangular, $A=I+M$ say.

The minimal polynomial $m_A(X)$ of $A$ is  $(X-1)^d$ for some $d\leqslant p$, and $A$ is diagonalisable if and only if $m_A$ is a product of distinct linear factors, that is, if and only if $m_A(X)=X-1$. That is, $A$ is diagonalisable if and only if $A=I$.

Now for an example all you need do is choose some non-zero $M$. (And of course @Gerry Myerson has written down the simplest example.)